# c++ coding standard #define header files

Tags: c++, standards, header-files

I am reading the book C++ Coding Standards: 101 Rules, Guidelines, and Best Practices, and it says that using `#define` is bad to use. When I was looking at some of the header files they have many `#define`s. If it's bad to use `#define`s, why is there so many? Thank you.

Comment: Most of the ones in the standard headers have legitimate uses. C++ offers better alternatives to some of the uses for macros.

Comment: Note that even though macros are generally not good to use in `C++`, you should still use include/header guards. These are done by using `#define`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`#define` are a bad practice because:

> ***They don't have any Scope:***

`#define`s don't respect scopes so there is no way to create a class scoped namespace. While variables can be scoped in classes.

> ***Weird magical numbers during compilation errors:***

If you are using `#define` those are replaced by the pre-processor at time of precompilation So if you receive an error during compilation, it will be confusing because the error message wont refer the macro name but the value and it will appear a sudden  value, and one would waste lot of time tracking it down in code.

> ***Debugging Problems:***

Also for same reasons mentioned in #2, while debugging `#define` won't provide much of an help really.

Hence it is much better idea to use `const` variables instead of a `#define`.
They are superior to `#define` in all above mentioned aspects.Only areas where `#define` can be really helpful are where you need actual textual replacement in code or in defining include header guards.

> **Why are `#define`widely used in C standard header files?**

One reason that comes to my mind is, In C(unlike C++) `const` declarations do not produce constant expressions.Which means prior to introduction of ***Variable length arrays*** in C standard one cannot write something like:

```
const int max_val = 100;  
int foos[max_val];
```

because in C `max_val` is not a compile time constant, and prior to introduction of VLA's array subscripts were needed to be compile time constants.
So one had to write this instead as:

```
#define MAX_VAL 100  
int foos[MAX_VAL];
```

Comment: I understand that. But why do many standard header files have them, for example stdlib.h?

Answer (score 2):

What that's probably referring to is the old C way of defining constants:

```
#define MAX_SOMETHING 100

int x = MAX_SOMETHING;
```

These constants aren't typed, they're expanded in place using a string substitution, and make it harder to debug since once the source is compiled it's not clear where that definition originated.

A more C++ way of doing it is:

```
const int max_something = 100;

int x = max_something;
```

Since this is a strongly typed value it is subject to all the required checks and appropriate conversions if required.

An additional benefit is that `const` values can be put into namespaces and classes for organizational purposes. A `#define` is global in scope so collisions are a concern, something that leads to awkwardly long names to avoid conflict.

Between `const` and `template`, which allows for a form of meta-programming C doesn't do natively, the number of occasions where `#define` is required is quite diminished. It's not entirely eliminated though, as without having the `#import` directive you will still need to add the old `#ifndef __HEADER_FILE_NAME__` guards to ensure things aren't included twice.

Comment: snap ;-) and some more char so I can post this

Answer (score 0):

The broad statment of the book is not so true - `#define` has its place for macro etc but for defining constants it is now not a good idea to use

eg

```
 #define FOO 257
```

is better done at

```
const int FOO=257;
```

This allows type checking because with the #define this becomes a bit odd

```
char c=FOO;
```