# How to summing element in array using taskloop on OMP

Tags: c++, openmp

I was trying to using taskloop to finding sum of element in array.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
using namespace std;
#define NUMTHREAD 6
#define SIZE 100
int main() {
    int* n = new int [SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
        n[i] = 1;
    }
    long sum =0;

#pragma omp parallel num_threads(NUMTHREAD)
    {
        #pragma omp taskloop
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
                 sum += n[i];
        }
    }
    cout << sum<< "\n";
        return 0;
}
```

but output is

```
600
```

It's should be `100`
I don't know why sum is shared.

I was trying to made sum not shared and for each thread.

```cpp
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(NUMTHREAD)
    {
        #pragma omp taskloop private(sum)
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
                 sum += n[i];
        }
    }
```

but Output is

```
0
```

IDK why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The `taskloop` construct is a [task-generating construct](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu47.html),  not a [worksharing-loop construct](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu41.html#x64-1290002.9.2).  You can read the following in [OpenMP specification](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu47.html):

> The taskloop construct is a task generating construct. When a thread
> encounters a taskloop construct, the construct partitions the
> iterations of the associated loops into explicit tasks for parallel
> execution.

In your case 6 threads encounter the taskloop construct, therefore the loop is executed 6 times, and you got a bigger result than expected.
To correct it you have to i) make sure that only a single thread executes the tasks generating construct, or ii) use a worksharing-loop construct.

2. There is a race condition at line `sum += n[i];`, as different threads update `sum` simultaneously. To correct it the best option is to use reduction (`reduction(+:sum)`)
3. In the second case the sharing attribute of `sum` is private, so the variable `sum` will be privatized. It means that a local variable is created, and only the value of the local variable is changed. It does not change the value of `sum` in the enclosing context, therefore you got `0`.

To sum up, here are the 2 alternatives mentioned above to correct your code:

i) using `single` construct and `taskloop`:

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(NUMTHREAD)
#pragma omp single nowait
{
    #pragma omp taskloop reduction(+:sum)
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
                sum += n[i];
    }
}
```

ii) using a worksharing-loop construct:

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(NUMTHREAD)
{
    #pragma omp for reduction(+:sum)
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
                sum += n[i];
    }
}
```

Some minor, off-topic comments:

1. The array (allocated by `new` operator) is never freed, you should use `delete` to deallocate it. As pointed out by [@VictorEijkhout](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2044454/victor-eijkhout) it is even better if you do not use `new` at all. Use `vector` or `array` from the std library.
2. You should prefer `const/constexpr int SIZE=100;` over `#define SIZE 100`. More details can be found e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12208222/c-coding-standard-define-header-files).
3. You should consider reading [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: 4. and don't use `new`. Vector or array from the std library.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Thank you, I have added your comment to the answer.